# jQuery delete preview before upload

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to create a multiple files input that preview images before upload them. The preview and delete functions are working, but when I try to submit it the images that were deleted are sent

View

```
<input type="file" accept="file_extension|image/*" id="postfile" name="postfile[]" multiple>
<output id="list"></output>
```

Javascript

```
function handleFileSelect(evt) {
    var files = evt.target.files; 
    for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {
      if (!f.type.match('image.*')) {
        continue;
      }
      var reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = (function(theFile) {
        return function(e) {
          var span = document.createElement('span');
          span.innerHTML = ['<img class="thumb" src="', e.target.result,
                            '" title="', escape(theFile.name), '"/><a href="#" class="remove">Remove</a>'].join('');
          document.getElementById('list').insertBefore(span, null);
          span.children[1].addEventListener("click", function(event){
            span.parentNode.removeChild(span);
          });
        };
      })(f);
      reader.readAsDataURL(f);
    }
  }

  document.getElementById('postfile').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you very much

Comment: there are plenty of wheels out there why are you creating your own?

Comment: It's not what I want, I want to submit multiple files in one form (array) and users can remove every files before sent

Comment: it's a saying *Don't reinvent the wheel* why don't you try Dropzone.js it has file preview, and has the capabilities to remove files

Comment: It's not what I want